# msys2 emacs shell and gdb: control-c/ctrl-c does not work

Tags: shell, emacs, gdb, msys

I have searched pretty extensively about this, but have found nothing in the last couple of years, or specifically for msys2.

Which really puzzles me since it makes using emacs (and therefore shell mode) and gdb within emacs pretty useless. Clearly, so much effort was put into msys2/mingw, but for those who live in emacs (me), it's not really a viable development environment.

So... is there any chance that I have missed a simple solution?!

I think a related issue is the error message when the shell starts up: "bash: cannot set terminal process group (-1): Inappropriate ioctl for device"

Comment: How about `C-c C-c` for interrupt? `C-c C-z` for stop? C-c C-\ for quit?  In the gdb buffer, type `C-h b` to see the key bindings in that buffer.

Comment: No, none of them work. Yes, I should have included that... C-c C-c does get echo'd as normal, just does not cause an interrupt of the running process. In the case of gdb, does not break into gdb and in the case of bash, does not end the program (easiest test is sleep 30)

Comment: are you using the emacs compiled for native windows? If so, it is probably using pipes instead ptys to start bash, hence no job control, no foreground process group (eg. gdb) to receive your signals. I remember having similar issues and tried emacs on cygwin, but it is way slower than using emacs on linux due to emulation layer, etc. Does `term` work on your setup?

Comment: If you're on Windows 10 have you considered bash for Windows instead? You'd probably get a more seamless environment for emacs (not personally tested though, just guessing).

Comment: I used: "pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-emacs" for the emacs I'm using. Not sure about "does term" work question, but when entered on the shell prompt, returns no such. Also, I use "runemancs" to start it. AND, the main issue is with not being able to interrupt gdb, although not breaking out of, say ping, in the shell is quite bad too!!

Comment: `M-x term` is an emacs function, an alternative shell wrapper that attempts to send keypresses transparently to the underlying shell.